Heston model calibration to option prices and implied volatility
I hope that you are having a great day,
I am trying to write a research paper on the Heston model deep calibration. I noticed during my literature review that the most common approach is to calibrate the model to implied volatility and not option prices. What is the rationale behind this ?
Thanks a lot

Deep ITM and OTM Option prices are not very sensitive to input parameters, while implied volatility is.

Implied volatility and option prices can be used interchangeably. Given the implied vol, you can find the market price using Black-Scholes formula (and vice versa).
If you are using Quantlib functions for calibration, it will do the translation for you.
Edit: Also depending upon the calibrator either can be used. Typically the calibration process attempts to find parameters for the Heston model that minimise the difference (for example the mean absolute difference or mean squared difference) between the prices produced by calibrated model parameters and the market prices.
